# Does an electron change its energy when the spin projection is changed?

Tags: energy, magnetic-fields, electrons, quantum-spin

When an electron changes its spin projection in a magnetic field does it receive or take energy?
When the initial spin projection is indefinite (as is according to QM) how much is that energy?

Answer (score 0):

In presence of a uniform magnetic field, the spin of a particle mostly enters the Hamiltonian, and therefore the energy, via a Zeeman term $ \hat{H}_{Zeeman}=-\mu\vec{B}\cdot\hat{\vec{S}}$, characterized by the scalar product of the magnetic field vector $\vec{B}$ and the spin operator $\hat{\vec{S}}$.

Given some spin state $|\chi\rangle$ consisting of a superposition of spin-up and spin-down along $\vec{B}$, the Zeeman energy contribution is given by the expectation value of the corresponding term in the Hamiltonian, i.e. by $\langle \hat{H}_{Zeeman} \rangle=\langle \chi | \hat{H}_{Zeeman} | \chi \rangle $. However, notice that it makes sense to consider such a contribution for an ensemble of electrons in most cases, interpreting the expectation value as a mean value.

Comment: 1.Do you say that the Energy received/taken is (half of mu.B) when the electron jumps from -half to +half spin? 2. Do you say that the E is indefinite when spin projection value is indefinite?

Comment: More precisely, a spin flip leads to an energy change of $2\mu |\vec{B}|$

Comment: And yes, the energy is indefinite in the sense that there is some uncertainty $\Delta\hat{H}$

Comment: What I don't understand is that: If one measures the Energy received/taken by a single electron than he would know what was the value of the projection of the spin before the flip hence before the measurement. But it is principally non-existent in the orthodox interpretation.

Comment: “The projection of the spin before the flip hence before the measurement”: what do you mean? And what is non-existent in the orthodox interpretation?

Comment: The energy received/taken by a single electron is dependent on the spin projection before the measurement (before application of B) and the projection of the spin immediately after B (maybe even linearly but doesn't matter). Right? Then Copenhagen says that projection of spin does not exist before B application. There is spin, but its projection is non-existent. Material objects on microscopic level, generally do not have definite properties prior to being measured, says Copenhagen interpretation which is most accepted of course.

Comment: @Mercury of course according to Copenhagen, the spin projection is undetermined before measuring it, and that’s why prior to the measurement one describes the system by means of some probability distribution regarding possible measurement outcomes, and the following expectation value. As a consequence you describe all other properties somehow depending on this “undetermined” observable (which are a function of it) by a similar expectation value. I guess that’s the right way to think about it